# C# implicit conversions and == operator

Tags: c#, operators, type-conversion, equals-operator

Some code for context:

```
class a
{

}

class b
{
    public a a{get;set;}
    public static implicit operator a(b b)
    {
        return b.a;
    }
}

  a a=null;
  b b=null;
  a = b;

  //compiler: cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type tralala...
  bool c = a == b;
```

Is it possible to use == operator on different type instances, where one can implicitly convert to another? What did i miss?

**Edit:**
If types must be the same calling ==, then why

```
int a=1;
double b=1;
bool c=a==b;
```

works?

Comment: I'd assume your int/double example works because they are value types, and not reference types...

Comment: That can be a reason. Only problem is - if so, it doesn't explain why exactly reference type can't perform conversion implicitly just like value types can.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `implicit` operator only works for assignment.

You want to overload the equality (`==`) operator, as such:

```
class a
{
    public static bool operator ==(a x, b y)
    {
        return x == y.a;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(a x, b y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
}

class b
{
    public a a{get;set;}
    public static implicit operator a(b b)
    {
        return b.a;
    }
}
```

This should then allow you to compare two objects of type `a` and `b` as suggested in your post.

```
var x = new a();
var y = new b();
bool c = (x == y); // compiles
```

**Note:**

I recommmend simply overriding the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method, as the compiler warns, but as you seem to want to supress them, you can do that as follows.

Change your class declaration of `a` to:

```
#pragma warning disable 0660, 0661
class a
#pragma warning restore 0660, 0661
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: and in this case the a == b expression will compile with no problems.

Comment: This seems like correct answer. Kind a figured out this too. Only - i think that operator overloading would be overkill in this case (it demands gethash() and equals() function overloading too :/ ).

Comment: Yeah, there are no restrictions on defining or using custom (overloaded) operators on user-defined types.

Comment: @Arnis L: They are only warnings fortunately. You can overriden them if you like (Equals can have the same logic as == and GetHashCode can just return a.GetHashCode() ^ b.GetHashCode()), or you can ignore/supress the warnings if you don't care.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress warning through code (have seen something like that somewhere)?

Comment: @Arnis L: Yep, see my updated post. Not sure it's that much more effort just to override them with a simple implementation however...

Comment: Enlighten me why that code i added after "Edit:" works and you will surely get accepted answer. :)

Comment: Oh right, I missed that bit of your question, sorry. I believe it's a compiler-specific feature (there are no operator overloads defined in System.Int32 or System.Double). In this case, b (the double) gets converted into an int before equating the objects of the same type. (It *may* be the other way around - a simple test will tell you.) Hopefully this all makes sense to you now.

Comment: The int gets converted to a double.  If the double were converted to int then double "2.1" would be equal to int "2"!

Comment: @Eric: Yeah, a widening rather than a narrowing conversion makes a lot more sense. The order of the operands is irrelevant, too.

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to use == operator on
>   different type instances, where one
>   can implicitly convert to another?

Yes.

> What did i miss?

Here's the relevant portion of the specification. You missed the highlighted word.

> The predefined reference type equality
>   operators require [that] both operands
>   are reference-type values or the
>   literal null. Furthermore, a **standard**
>   implicit conversion exists from the
>   type of either operand to the type of
>   the other operand.

A user-defined conversion is by definition not a standard conversion. These are reference types. Therefore, the predefined reference type equality operator is not a candidate.

> If types must be the same calling ==,
>   then why [double == int] works?

Your supposition that the types must be the same is incorrect. There is a standard implicit conversion from int to double and there is an equality operator that takes two doubles, so this works.

I think you also missed this bit:

> It is a compile-time error to use the
>   predefined reference type equality
>   operators to compare two references
>   that are known to be different at
>   compile-time. For example, if the
>   compile-time types of the operands are
>   two class types A and B, and if
>   neither A nor B derives from the
>   other, then it would be impossible for
>   the two operands to reference the same
>   object. Thus, the operation is
>   considered a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you need to actually override the == operator for the types you are interested in.  Whether the compile/runtime will still complain even if the types are implicity convertable is something you'll have to experiment with.

```
public static bool operator ==(a a, b b)
    {
        //Need this check or we can't do obj == null in our Equals implementation
        if (((Object)a) == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return a.Equals(b);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively just use Equals implementations like ole6ka suggests and ensure that the implementation does the type casting you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx

> In each case, one parameter must be
>   the same type as the class or struct
>   that declares the operator (...)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
 bool c = a.Equals(b);
```

Comment: This won't be useful in particular case, cause i'm abusing lambdas and builder pattern to create dynamic property setter like this: factory.Object.With(object=>object.MyProp==newPropValue).Create()