# Docuementation for how the == operator resolves types when comparing value types

Tags: c#

I am wondering if someone can point me to the official documentation for how the `==` operator resolves implicit conversions.

I have this struct:

```
public readonly struct Name
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public Name(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid name.");

        _value = name;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Name name) => name._value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Then I run the following code:

```
var a = new Name("a");
var b = new Name("a");

var eq = a == b;
```

[image]

Because I have defined the implicit conversion operator to string on the struct, this equality check returns `true`.

It has somehow resolved that `Name` can be converted to `string`, and uses the `string` comparison since `==` doesn't work on user defined structs without specifically overloading it.

I have tried to find documentation for how the `==` operator resolves which types it can compare, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think `==` can compare anything as long as it's from the same type. If one of them is not from the same type, it needs to be be converted first.

Comment: @Steven But it has somehow resolved that `Name` can be converted to `string`, and uses the `string` comparison since `==` doesn't work on user defined structs without specifically overloading it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#reference-type-equality-operators

Comment: Start at [Binary operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#binary-operator-overload-resolution) but expect to have to follow the links from there and be aware that there's not going to be a page that *specifically* talks about `==` and implicit conversions. You have to read and understand these bits and then follow the *implications* of what they describe

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/892024/11683

Comment: I don't know why you're being fobbed off, this seems to be to be a genuinely interesting question. When I set up the same situation but with a custom class `S` (which implements `operator ==`) rather than `string`, it *won't*  use that!

Comment: @AakashM Because a class is [a reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/893592/11683), as opposed to the `struct Name`?

Comment: @GSerg I have a `struct Name` just like asker, except that instead of `string` I have defined my own class `S` (which has an `operator ==`), and my `Name` has an implicit conversion to `S` rather than `string`. The compiler does not allow me `a == b`.  What's special about `string`, that this example compiles? And whatever it is, where does it say it in the docs?

Answer (score -2):

You may view the following documentation regarding equality operators from the official MSDN site.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#reference-type-equality-operators